# How can I use an .htaccess for specific path to listen child path

Tags: php, reactjs, .htaccess

ReactJS application sits inside page path - [www.example.com/some-path](http://www.example.com/some-path)

Reactjs App is part of page and not cover full page - so we cant add extra subdirectory and add reactjs there.

How to change htaccess to make situation where all paths after some-path - (some-path/foo or some-path/foo1) listening my reactjs app inside some-path

At the moment it works only if I visit some-path, but if I try to open some-path/foo then it takes server path that is empty and send empty page 404.

I have deployed multiple working single-page applications (reactJS) into main route of server and used htacces like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

There is no any some-path folder's inside server because it is wordpress application where we hold our react app.

Can anyone help?

Comment: is www.example.com/some-path the wordpress and are you using a .htacess for wordpress already?

Comment: yes, is wordpress page and there is basic wordpress htaccess

Comment: And have you tried to apply the scheme you know for the other react-js apps and combine it with the wordpress rewrites? It sounds to me this is what you're looking for, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm, im not confident with wordpress and htaccess, and the problem is also that we need smallest possbile solution for changes in client server. I mean we need to change only htaccess to make this move and not touch any other settings. Because wordpress is mostly client business and its not in our hands to change. Or can you make an example for me about what you meant?

Comment: I don't want to ruin your day, but if the URL paths do cross wordpress _and_ the react-app its a delicate configuration task. So perhaps consider if it is worth. Can't you put the react app in a subdirectory of its own or even a virstualhost of its own?

Comment: Alternatively search for the term "reactpress" it may give you some pointers - I've never used it so this is not a recommendation, but you might be interested in existing solutions maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it doesn't help me with the server problem. Maybe someone has to offer a solution without htaccess -like some server settings then.

Comment: htaccess is server settings actually. not the whole, but effectively directory (and beneath) server settings. it's pretty powerful as well (and limited to some regards, but mature). the main field of action I see is the mixing with wordpress which makes it pretty individually (depends on wordpress permalink / URL config as well), which is why I did hope you can gather some infos from existing things like reactpress (or alike). so sorry it didn't play well.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution

I made its own directory for (some-path)

Inside that path added:

1. index.php - with wordpress (header, footer) - middle of that added my reactjs application
2. .htaccess to listen that reactjs app - now all routes runs well